# Importing data using ImportJSON to Google Sheets, select value output based on column name?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I'm trying to import financial data from Yahoo Finance into Google Sheets.
I just learned about ImportJSON.

I use ImportJSON with this link: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/EDIT?modules=defaultKeyStatistics 
I have stock tickers in column A of my spreadsheet, I want to pull a certain value from the link above for the corresponding ticker.

I tried this: `=INDEX(ImportJSON("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/"& A2&"?modules=defaultKeyStatistics"),2,69)`

However it seems that the column don't correspond to the same value for each ticker as i'm getting mixed results. 
Is there a way for me to INDEX using the column name rather than number?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can I ask you about the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Its complex!

JSON and spreadsheet-like data don't go together very easily because JSONs are inherently nested, which is not easy to represent in a tabular way. Often the keys will appear in a different order each time, which is why you may be getting inconsistent results.

For this reason, I suggest you get familiar with Apps Script because it is a much friendlier way to interact with JSON than via in sheet functions. This way you can easily call values by name because JSON, after all, is JavaScript Object notation, and Apps Script is a type of JavaScript!

#### Sample Apps Script

To illustrate this, here is a script I just wrote to extract data from the particular JSON you posted. It can work as a function in sheet too. Below is demonstrated how to use it:

```js
/**
 * Returns 2D array of values. i.e.
 * Value, Raw, Fmt, LongFmt
 * sharesShort, 9890638, 9.89M, 9,890,638
 */
function getJsonValue(url) {
  // Fetch the JSON
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  let text = response.getContentText();
  let json = JSON.parse(text);

  // Initialize the output array
  let output = [];

  // Navigate to where the main data is
  let stats = json.quoteSummary.result[0].defaultKeyStatistics

  // Adding headers to the output
  let header = ["Value", "Raw", "Fmt", "LongFmt"]
  output.push(header)

  // For each key in stats, add:
  // Value, Raw, Fmt, LongFmt
  for (let attribute in stats) {
    // initialize row array
    let row = [];
    // Add Value to array
    row.push(attribute);

    // Check if the contents of the attribute is an object, else add blank row
    if (typeof(stats[attribute]) == "object" && stats[attribute] != null) {
      // if the object contains raw, fmt, longfmt, then add to row, else add null
      "raw" in stats[attribute] ? row.push(stats[attribute].raw) : row.push(null)
      "fmt" in stats[attribute] ? row.push(stats[attribute].fmt) : row.push(null)
      "longFmt" in stats[attribute] ? row.push(stats[attribute].longFmt) : row.push(null)
    } else {
        row.push(null);
        row.push(null);
        row.push(null);
    }
    // Add row to output
    output.push(row)
  }
  // Return 2D array
  return output
}
```

You can use it like this:

[image]

Or in code:

```js
function test() {
  
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  let output = getJsonValue("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/EDIT?modules=defaultKeyStatistics")

  let rows = output.length
  let cols = output[0].length
  let range = sheet.getRange(1,1,rows, cols)
  range.setValues(output)

}
```

This script is mainly for you to adapt yourself, depending on the structure of the JSON that you are using.

#### References

- [Main Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Url Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)
- [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect. I can't get it to work though. I'm very new to all this so bare with me. When I go to Tools > Script, I add the script, run it, give it permissions and save it. However when I try and activate the function in my sheet nothing comes up. When I go to my Script Editors Projects section it looks like the script isn't linked to my sheet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tools > script _within_ the spreadsheet, right? When you say "nothing comes up" - no errors or anything? It does take a few seconds, and the first time can sometimes take longer. Also, the script may come up as a separate script, but as long as it was opened _from the spreadsheet_ then it is "container bound" to it.

Comment: No errors, nothing. I'm in the sheet, click on Tools > Script, the script editor opens up an existing project. I tried both creating a new project as well as adding a new script to the existing project. Either way doesn't work. When I go to my projects overview I can see that the new script isn't linked to a sheet. Heres a copy of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqBOFw49SQy1uH03uSVqteq0M0YLTtVml-TT3Xybjxw/edit?usp=sharing, sorry to ask, but could you try adding it to see if i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I opened your script and added a new `gs` file with my code, and then created a new sheet to demonstrate it. You should be able to see it now.

Comment: Oh god, i'm dumb. I thought that the two sections of code you posted were separate things, didn't realize I had to add both to the script editor.... Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No worries, you didn't have to add in both, just the first, longer one. The `test` function is just a way to do the same thing but all from within Apps Script.

Comment: One last question if you don't mind. I want to pull data from this link as well https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=incomeStatementHistory - if I open the link in my browser I can see the data, when I try and import it via =getJsonValue("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=incomeStatementHistory") I only get column headings without the values.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it won't work because that new link has a different structure of JSON. The first one had this structure: `quoteSummary.result[0].defaultKeyStatistics` and there all the data was neatly organized in keys. While the new one has `quoteSummary.result[0].incomeStatementHistory` and within that it seems to have different objects, some with lists, so the function would need to be adapted to extract the information from that specific format.

Comment: Ah I see, i'll have to find another way. Thanks again